# Javascript scope basics : .bind or self =this?

Tags: javascript, scope, bind

For me the below code do the same thing but I'm not totally sure so I would like to be sure:

```
var self = this;
this.param = 5;
var listener = sub.on('change', function() {
     self.param = 10;
});
```

Is it identical to ?:

```
this.param = 5;
var listener = sub.on('change', function() {
     this.param = 10;
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: i think both are different since when you call this inside the 'change' even scope will be transferred to sub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not *identical*, but for your purposes in the example you posted they're close enough in that you get the same effect. The goal is to have a reference to the value of `this` *outside* the event handler later when the handler is actually invoked. Both of those alternatives have that effect.

The `.bind()` function does a few other things that won't make any difference in a simple case like this.

*edit* — and definitely note the fix that @deceze posted in his answer.

Here's an example of when the two are different: if the `self` variable were to change, then your event handler would behave differently. It's probably not very likely that you'd change it, but it's a possibility (a bug could be introduced).  With `.bind()`, you get a function that really can't be changed; nothing can override the binding that you set up that way.

Comment: of course they are not 'identical' but can we say it achieve exactly the same thing ? any trap ?

Comment: @FrançoisRichard both will achieve different things

Comment: @FrançoisRichard there's no "trap" that I can imagine, though in some ways the "bind" version is a little more robust. For example, with the "self" way, the event handler would stop working (or work differently) if the "self" variable were to change. That's not likely, but it's a difference.

Comment: ok, thank you , please add your last comment in your answer it's interesting.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
sub.on('change', function() {
     this.param = 10;
}.bind(this))
            ^
 misplaced parenthesis
```

You want to bind `this` for the callback function, not for `on()`. If you fix that, the results will be the same for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Please also consider that there is notable performance results from both (actually they are 3) ways.

Check out https://jsperf.com/bind-vs-self-closure/17

Doing a closured reference seems to be way faster (actually 100x) than binding context.